# TweenMax in Starling, possible issue with radian conversion

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework, gsap

I'm trying to use TweenMax.to() in an app with the ease option of Circ.easeInOut while rotating a view. I used the same thing without Starling and there was no problem. But in Starling, when the animation is about to finish, the view speeds up suddenly and then slows down. I guess it's because Starling only works with radians, and somewhere in the code TweenMax uses degree values.

Same problem occurs between two rotating animations: I mean when the first animation is finished, a second one is called in the onComplete method and the same sudden speeding-up problem is seen during this transition.

Any solution?

Comment: Please let us look at the part of your code where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is something else. I can tell you definitively that TweenMax will ease a value the same from 0 to 360 as it would from 0 to 2*Math.PI. Look somewhere else for the problem, such as a second Tween being called, or the duration of the existing tween being modified.

The "ease" of TweenMax applies to the rate it takes to change from one value to another, over time. It does not do any sort of unit conversion on the values themselves.